# Github can not preview Markdown as it should be

Tags: github, pycharm, markdown

This is how I wrote Markdown:

```
#EHSAN SHIRZADI
###Python backend developer - DevOps engineer
|![](images/tel2.png)+9811111111111|![](images/email2.png)A.B@gmail.com|![](images/web2.png)www.web.com|
|---|---|---|
|![](images/stack2.png)Stackoverflow|![](images/linkdin2.png)Linkedin|![](images/github2.png)Github|
###About
I'm a senior backend developer and DevOps engineer with +18 years of experience in programming. I'm passionate about learning new technologies and I believe the best way to learn is by doing in a fun way.
It's my pleasure to work on the edge of technology.
###Education 
- Master of science in computer software engineering – University of Tehran – 2012-2014
- Bachelor of science in computer software engineering – Khayyam university of Mashhad 2008-2010
```

This is how PyCharm preview shows:
[image: Pycharm preview for markdown]

And this is what GitHub shows:

[image: GitHub preview for Markdown]

How to fix problem with GitHub preview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a space after your heading hashes.

https://docs.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax#headings